# MAVEN: How to run something BEFORE each plugin execution

Tags: maven, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I have the following script, that works.  It starts a docker mysql container, and initializes the database before running several executions of the liquibase plugin that run different stuff.

```
function die { mvn docker:stop ; exit 1; }

function initializeDatabase {
   docker exec -it mysql-1 mysql -uroot -proot \
   -e "DROP USER IF EXISTS 'myuser'@'%';" \
   -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;" \
   -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;" \
   -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';" \
   -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%';"
}

mvn docker:start && sleep 10

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution1 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution2 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution3 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution4 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution5 || die

initializeDatabase || die

mvn liquibase:update@execution6 || die

mvn docker:stop
```

It occurs to me that I could just have the docker start happen during the pre-integration-test phase and have all the liquibase executions run during the integration-test phase and then have the docker stop in the post-integration-test phase.  However, I don't know how to initialize the database using the root user before each execution of the liquibase plugin.

Any thoughts on how I could do this so that it would just happen seamlessly as part of the maven build lifecycle?  Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to take a deep look into https://www.testcontainers.org/ ....

Comment: @khmarbaise I got it working with testcontainers, but it takes 12 minutes instead of 6.

Comment: Maybe you could pre fill the database in a difference process instead of every time...and reuse that created container during the other test? Unfortunately I don't know the details ...